# Put the second column on top when narrow viewport

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to have 3 columns - Left column (1) text, which can grow or shrink, second a fixed width image (2), and a third, text (3) - which can grow or shrink, but should be the same as (1).

That's easy. BUT for narrow viewports, they should stack with the (2) Image on top, then under that the left column (1), and under that the right column (3)

I am using bootstrap 4.1, but can also use regular flexbox - if I knew how...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order".
Set the elements as mobile first(narrow viewport), then change the order of the elements in Tablet and desktop views.